# BERT Pre-training accuracy not increasing

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model

I am trying to pretrain BERT on dataset (wiki103) which contains 150k sentences. After 12 epochs nsp (next sentence prediction) task gives accuracy around 0.76 (overfits if I continue with more epochs) and mlm (masked language modeling) task starts from 0.01 acc and goes till 0.2 at max. What is wrong here? Can I stop nsp at one point and continue to do mlm for longer period of time? My train loader length is 2486 (2486 training steps per epochs) which means 40*2486=99440 training steps.

Here is model config and training config

```
class Train_Config():
""" Hyperparameters for training """
seed: int = 391275 # random seed
batch_size: int = 64
lr: int = 1e-5 # learning rate
n_epochs: int = 40 # the number of epoch
# `warm up` period = warmup(0.1)*total_steps
# linearly increasing learning rate from zero to the specified value(5e-5)
warmup: float = 0.1
is_dibert: bool = False


class Model_Config():
vocab_size: int = 30522  # Size of Vocabulary
hidden_size: int = 768  # Dimension of Hidden Layer in Transformer Encoder
num_hidden_layers: int = 8  # Numher of Hidden Layers
num_attention_heads: int = 8  # Numher of Heads in Multi-Headed Attention Layers
intermediate_size: int = 768 * 4  # Dimension of Intermediate Layers in Positionwise Feedforward Net
# activ_fn: str = "gelu" # Non-linear Activation Function Type in Hidden Layers
max_len: int = 312  # Maximum Length for Positional Embeddings
n_segments: int = 2  # Number of Sentence Segments
attention_probs_dropout_prob: int = 0.1
```

Comment: What is nsm in this case?

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa my bad. It is Next sentence prediction. Changed now in question. Thanks.